# excel: vba to merge sheets and rewrite on it

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I was trying to find a way to merge two sheets in a single sheet using VBA. During my research I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13687179/6088173) solution by Scott Holtzman that sort of works for what I want so I've changed the code to fit in my sheets as you can see below:

```
Sub CombinarPlanilhas()

   Dim wks As Worksheet
   Set wks = Sheets("Plan5")

   With Sheets("Plan2")

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("A1:K" & lastrow).Copy wks.Range("A" & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

   End With

   With Sheets("Plan4")

    lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("A2:K" & lastrow).Copy wks.Range("A" & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

   End With


End Sub
```

As I need to run the code more than once, I changed the code a little bit so my merged sheet `Plan5` will always be there and just its contents will be updated.

The problem is when I don't have nothing in my `Plan4` besides the header. The code should copy nothing from `Plan4` and copy everything from `Plan2`. Although when this situation occurs the header is been copied as you can see below:

This is Plan2:
[image]

This is Plan4:
[image]

And this is happening in Plan5:
[image]

I couldn't understand why this is happening since I'm copying from A2 to last row at this part of code:

```
With Sheets("Plan4")

        lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A2:K" & lastrow).Copy wks.Range("A" & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

       End With
```

I really don't know how to solve this issue... So any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: @pnuts yes, you're right... I was just not considering the header something to count since I know it exists on this sheet, you know? I'll edit the question. Anyway, I'll try this and I think it should work.

Comment: You are copying range `A2:K1`, which seems to be valid for Excel.

Comment: @EganWolf I got it now... Since the last row will be the header the code is copying it, but I don't want this to happen.